# jQuery button click issue

Tags: html, jquery

I am facing problem regarding jquery button click,

Here, the link what I am going to achive http://jsfiddle.net/Xzy9T/19/

Cam you help to debug this. Thanks, When I click to submit button, it seems that the click button is not running, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to change:

```
$(".sendbutton_form1").click(function() {...
```

for

```
 $("#sendbutton_form1").click(function() {...
```

Because your selector on the button is the id, not the class.

Answer (score 2):

Change `$(".sendbutton_form1").click(function() { ...` to `$("#sendbutton_form1").click(function() {` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

`$(".sendbutton_form1").click(function() {`

to

> $("#sendbutton_form1").click(function() {

You were referring to the classname "sendbutton_form1" in the former where it should have been referring to an ID.